# VSFTPD: Using MySQL authenticated virtual users disables system users

Tags: ftp

I've set up virtual users paired with a SQL-configured pam file on CentOS, but logging in with system users no longer work. How would I make it so system users can still login when configured with virtual users? Would this be in the pam file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure PAM to accept either MySQL or passwd authentication, probably using the `sufficient` option like so:

```
auth    sufficient  pam_mysql.so
auth    sufficient  pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

You probably need to configure the `account` type similarly.